# which version (jquery.min.js)using for datetimepicker field

Tags: jqgrid

which version (**jquery.min.js**)working for datetimepicker.. client side it's working good but server side (javaEE IDE)getting datetime not displayed ..i checked all libraray files getting problem in **jquery.min.js** file only 
which version suitable for datetimepicker ..Please any one help for me

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery UI's date time picker, then you must check their documentation about minimum Jquery version required for the date time picker to work.

http://jqueryui.com/

May be you have not uploaded jquery UI .js file to your server.

Check which plug-in is required to use date time picker.

Comment: Did this work? If it did, may be you can mark this answer as correct.

Comment: i import http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js this libarary file also ..

Comment: you can try firebug firefox plugin and check which file the browser is looking for.

Comment: my problem is datetimepicker worked in client side but in the server side not working .i am checking whole code the probelm is jquery.min.js related datetimepicker code ..how to use firebug firefox???